# How can I delete the users datafile in Oracle using SQL?

Tags: oracle, ddl, tablespace

I have tried dropping the datafile by itself but I get this error.

```
SQL> alter tablespace USERS drop datafile '/u01/app/oracle/oradata/orcl/users01.dbf';
alter tablespace USERS drop datafile '/u01/app/oracle/oradata/orcl/users01.dbf'
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-03261: the tablespace USERS has only one file
```

I have also tried taking the tablespace offline and dropping the whole tablespace but that doesn't work either.

```
SQL> drop tablespace users including contents and datafiles;
drop tablespace users including contents and datafiles
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-12919: Can not drop the default permanent tablespace
```

Edit: This is for an assignment to simulate the failure of a datafile that I will be recovering. I would delete it manually but the assignment is requiring me to  use SQL.

Comment: "*Can not drop the default permanent tablespace*" is pretty clear isn't it? You need to make a different tablespace the default tablespace before you can drop `USERS`

Comment: One (or more) users has the `USERS` tablespace set as the default tablespace.  You'll need to change that before you can drop the tablespace.

Comment: I just want to drop the datafile and not the whole tablespace to simulate a hardware failure.

Comment: Create another file in that tablespace, and drop the file you wanted to drop in the first place. If the assignment is to drop and recover 1 file, that should work out just nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want to drop the datafile to simulate a hardware failure, than you can simply delete them from the machine.

You can know where are stored your datafile using a simple query :

```
select name
from V$DATAFILE;
```

This will give the path to all data files.

**Edit :** To simulate an even more cool system failure to make sure your backup scripts or whatever you are testing is properly working, you could also corrupt the data (open a file and write some random gibberish in it)

Comment: Yeah that's what I ended up doing. Our instructor realized it wasn't as easy as one SQL statement so he said we can just delete it manually.

Answer (score 4):

Since the USERS is the default tablespace, you can't drop any of its datafiles and would get the error ORA-12919. 
The solution is to create another tablespace and then change the default tablespace:

`SQL> CREATE TABLESPACE USERS_TEMP DATAFILE '/u01/app/oracle/oradata/orcl/users_temp_01.dbf' size 10M AUTOEXTEND ON;

SQL>alter database default tablespace USERS_TEMP;`

Now you can remove USERS:

`SQL>DROP TABLESPACE USERS INCLUDING CONTENTS AND DATAFILES;`

To delete the datafile located on 'app\Ora11gHome\oradata\someName' , you must  turn the database service off. Open Oracle Administration Assistant and stop the service, now you can delete the file.